# Instanciar um objeto com parâmetro

Tags: php

O que acontecen quando eu instancio um objeto? Por exemplo, em Java, quando eu instancio um objeto, faço algo parecido com isso:

```
$this->ConexaoBanco = new mysqli();
```

Porém esta classe abaixo no PHP, tenho que instanciar com alguns valores por parâmetro, mas eu não consigo entender o que está acontecendo.

Esses valores que estou passando por parâmetro, vão para onde? Para algum atributo da classe `mysqli`? E se for, qual é o atributo? Não entendo como posso instanciar um objeto passando valores por parâmetro.

```
class classBancoDados {
protected $ConexaoBanco;

public function AbrirConexao() {
    $this->ConexaoBanco = new mysqli($this->IdServidor,"root","root","db_hotel");}
```

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), `mysqli` é uma classe, e ao fazer `new mysqli(...)` você está chamando o construtor, passando os dados que ela precisa para se conectar ao banco ([veja também que se vc não passa nada](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), ele usa valores default). Se internamente a classe vai setar algum atributo dela ou se só vai usar os dados para se conectar e depois descartá-los, isso é detalhe interno de implementação que não interessa para quem a chama.

Answer (score 1):

Quando você cria uma classe pensando no contexto de Programação Orientada a Objetos, é feito algo parecido com `new Classe()`. Ao fazer isto, você está criando uma instância da `Classe`. Nesta questão, temos nossos métodos chamados de construtores ou melhor `constructor` que ele é sempre inicializado quando fazemos uma instância do objeto.

### Exemplo

```
class Pessoa {
    prviate string nome;
    constructor(nomePeloConstrutor: string) {
        this.name = nomePeloConstrutor;
    }
}

const pessoa = new Pessoa('Vagner');
```

### O que isto quer dizer?

No exemplo acima temos uma classe chamada `Pessoa` que tem uma propriedade chamada `nome`, vamos supor que ao instanciarmos a nossa classe, queremos já darmos o nome da pessoa para este objeto que será gerado. Para isto, precisamos passar no método construtor da classe, o nome que queremos, isto serve para qualquer coisa que você esteja querendo inicializar já com um valor sem precisar criar métodos `get` e `set`.

### Seu caso

No seu contexto, quando criamos conexão de banco de dados, obrigatoriamente muitas vezes, precisamos passar valores para os métodos construtores de quem você está instanciando. Então, ao fazer `new mysqli($this->IdServidor,"root","root","db_hotel")` você está passando um valor padrão logo que faz a instância e definindo este valores para as propriedades dentro desta classe.

#### Respostas das suas perguntas

- Esses valores que estou passando por parâmetro vai para onde?

Pensando em termo de classe eles são passados para o método construtor.

- Qual é o atributo?

Para podermos saber qual atributo é em cada lugar, podemos procurar na documentação da biblioteca por exemplo, ou dependendo, caso você deixe o seu mouse em cima da instância, pode aparecer uma mini janela dizendo quais valores aquela classe precisa receber para seu método construtor.

### Referências

[Programação orientada a objetos](https://www.dca.fee.unicamp.br/cursos/PooJava/metodos/construtor.html#:%7E:text=O%20(pseudo%2D)m%C3%A9todo%20construtor,retorno%20%2D%2D%20nem%20mesmo%20void.)

[Construtores em Java](https://www.devmedia.com.br/construtores-em-java/21997)

[Construtores em PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.decon.php)